# Having 2 forms of strings in an array and converting between them dynamically at run time in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to **refer to a finite list of strings in two ways** -

**1.** User-readable english name

**2.** Code usable name without blanks that I can pass to my API

Not too many strings, maybe 10-20 strings at the max.

> **Example**,
>
> **USER READABLE** -------- **WILL PASS TO API**
>
> Country Name-----------countryName
>
> City Name---------------cityName
>
> No Of Employees-------numEmployees

**Question :** How do I implement this ? Would it be possible to create a function like this and use at runtime?

- formatString( {english name} , "english-to-code-name")
- formatString( {code name} , "code-to-english-name")

Comment: Store both because the function you propose is not simple and secondly you might want other languages in the future.

Comment: Yeah, can you give me some guidance on how to go about implementing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would typically define an object that provides a mapping from internal name to user-readable name, like so:

```js
const userReadable = {
  apicountryName: 'Country Name',
  cityName: 'City Name',
  numEmployees: 'No Of Employees'
};
```

Then, if you want to convert an API string `apiString` to the corresponding user-readable string, you just use `userReadable[apiString]`.

You could also iterate over all the possible strings, define a reverse map if needed, etc.